# Prove that level set is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

It's probably straightforward to most of you, but I was trying to solve the following exercise during self study on "measure integral and probability".
Prove that if f is a Lebesgue measurable function, then the level set $\{x:f(x)=a\}$ is measurable for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Using Cantor intersection theorem (I think...), we can rewrite
$$\{x:f(x)=a\} \equiv \bigcap_n \{x:a-\frac{1}{n}\leq f(x)\leq a+\frac{1}{n}\}$$
Since f is measurable any set on the R.H.S is measurable, and so is the intersection.
Is that correct, are there any parts that need more justifications ?

Comment: Can you not just say that $\{x:f(x)=a\}=f^{-1}(\{a\})$ and is hence measurable since singletons are measurable in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I may be wrong... but in your answer it seems that you mean that the set $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is a singleton, whereas it is not always the case (think for ex about the constant function, $f(x)=a$, the inverse image is the whole real line, not a singleton).

Comment: @zebullon You should read again ThisIsMe's comment. Where do you see a singleton except $\{a\}$ there?

Comment: @zebullon The singleton ThisIsMe is referring to is the set $\{a\}$.

Comment: English is not my first language, but it seems that ThisIsMe meant that the set $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ was a singleton. Regardless, the fact that the image set is a singleton, is clear to me. But, checking for measurability is about the preimage set $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ (which does not have to be a singleton), not checking the image set $\{a\}$

Comment: @zebullon What I meant is that the set you want to be measurable is the inverse image of a singleton, hence the inverse image of a measurable set under the measurable function $f$...

Answer (score 3):

Let $\phi_n$ be a continuous function such that $\phi_n(a) = 1$ and $\phi_n(y) = 0$ if $|y-a| \ge 2^{-n}$. Now $\phi_n(f(x))$ will be meausurable and therefore also $\psi(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi_n(f(x))$. Now we have that $\psi(x)=1$ on the level set and zero otherwise that is it's the characteristic function for the level set. As it's a measurable characteristic function then the set itself is measurable.